# Excel spreadsheet issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible for Excel to see what today is and then look at a master file to determine what the next delivery day would be. For instance: Store abc has a Mon Wed Fri delivery I enter information in a spreadsheet for them today which is Tuesday and Excel auto populates Wednesday into a column.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have made an answer that you're looking for, but with **primitive IF loop** to satisfy and display the answer that you wanted. Look at the screenshot below.
[image]

These are the formulas used. The words in *italics* are comments

> Column A = No formula - just the date of order being placed -

_

> Column B = 'TEXT(A1,"ddd")

*This returns the day of order placement*

> Column C =
>   '=IF(B2="Sat",A2+2,IF(B2="Sun",A2+1,IF(B2="Tue",A2+1,IF(B2="Thu",A2+1,A2))))'

*Finds out the next possible delivery date where Mon, Wed and Fri are available delivery days for the store*

> Column D = 'TEXT(C1,"ddd")

*This returns the day of order delivery*

Comment: If anyone has a better formula for __`column C`__ please edit or comment my answer

Comment: You might want to note in the answer that Today() won't leave a persistent date.  It would be handy for a one-time lookup but if the table is built on that, the date will change every day when the sheet is refreshed.

Comment: removed the `Today()` function - thanks for the heads up

Comment: Another way to do col C:  =A2+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2,1),1,0,1,0,1,0,2)